# Acumatica refer custom field to another custom field on different screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

I have created 2 custom fields(UsrFFA and UsrFreeFreightDay) as below in the Customers Screen.[Customers Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTG7V.png)

Then I created similar fields on the Sales Order Screen as below
[Sales Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnoT.png)

I want these fields on Sales Order screen to populate values for respective Customer ID.

I went through the training material T200 and found this code

```
 protected void SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender,PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
 SOOrder order = e.Row as SOOrder;
 BAccount customer =
 PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOOrder.customerID>(sender, order)
 as BAccount;
 if (customer != null)
 {
 Contact defContact = PXSelect<Contact,
 Where<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Contact.bAccountID>>,
 And<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<Contact.contactID>>>>>
 .Select(Base, customer.BAccountID, customer.DefContactID);
 if (defContact != null)
 {
 ContactExt contactExt = PXCache<Contact>
 .GetExtension<ContactExt>(defContact);
 sender.SetValue<SOOrderExt.usrCRVerified>(order,
 contactExt.UsrCreditRecordVerified);
 }
 }
}
```

I am not able to understand this code and how should I use it in my customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize the attributes on the SOOrder field in the following way:

**For UsrFFA field**

```
[PXDBString(100)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="FFA", Visible = true, Enabled = false)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOOrder.customerID, BAccountExt.usrFFA>))]
```

**For UsrFreeFreightDay field**

```
[PXDBString(100)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Free Freight Day", Visible = true, Enabled = false)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOOrder.customerID, BAccountExt.usrFreeFreightDay>))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to FieldUpdated handler for the SOOrder.CustomerID field and populate your custom fields on the Sales Order screen in the same way as shown in **Example 5.2: Inserting a Default Detail Data Record** of the T200 training class:

```
protected virtual void ShipmentLine_ProductID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain the new data record that contains the updated
    // values of all data fields
    ShipmentLine line = (ShipmentLine)e.Row;
    line.Description = string.Empty;
    if (line.ProductID != null)
    {
        Product product = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<ShipmentLine.productID>(sender, line) as Product;
        if (product != null)
        {
            // Copy the product name to the description of the shipment line
            line.Description = product.ProductName;
        }
    } 
}
```

You might also check **Step 3.1: Adding the FieldUpdated Event Handler (CustomerMaint)** and **Step 5.2: Customizing Business Logic for the Sales Orders form (SOOrderEntry)** from the T300 training class for additional samples.

The code snippet below should accomplish desired results on the Sales Orders screen. If you still have issues understanding the code below, I highly recommend you to go through the T300 training class for very detailed hands-on exercises with step-by-step instructions.

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var order = e.Row as SOOrder;
        if (order.CustomerID != null)
        {
            var customer = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOOrder.customerID>(sender, order) as BAccountR;
            if (customer != null)
            {
                var customerExt = customer.GetExtension<BAccountExt>();
                var orderExt = order.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
                orderExt.UsrFFA = customerExt.UsrFFA;
                orderExt.UsrFreeFreightDay = customerExt.UsrFreeFreightDay;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand this code and how should I use it in my customization.
 I have edited the question

Comment: I used the above code in my customization but it still didn't show the result. Do we have to use SetValue to set values to new fields?

Comment: The SetValue method is 100% identical to a simple property value assignment. Have you tried to restart IIS or recycle app pool after applying the customization? There might be some legacy extension instances cached on your web server, that prevent the customization to work as expected. If restarting web server won't help, try to debug your code in VS and verify that your SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldUpdated event gets raised and assign values to the custom fields.

Comment: I restarted IIS but still couldn't get the result...i will try debugging the code in VS