# Acumatica - Copy custom field contents from SO to IN

Tags: acumatica

I have a similar type of issue as in

[Acumatica refer custom field to another custom field on different screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493389/acumatica-refer-custom-field-to-another-custom-field-on-different-screen)

except that I am using custom source fields.

I created and added 2 fields to the SO Line to capture EDI data needed for invoicing. I created 2 new fields on the invoice line with the same name (different data class of course) on the SO Invoice form. Below is the code for 1 field on each of the forms:

SO301000 (Sales Orders):

```
[PXDBString(3)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Cust.Invoice Line Nbr.")]
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOLineExt.usrCInvLine, ARTranExt.usrCInvLine>))]
```

SO303000 (Invoices):

```
[PXDBString(3)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Cust.Invoice Line Nbr.")]
```

It compiles but the data is not being copied to the invoice when created from shipment. I also added 1 of the fields to the shipment form for testing purposes but it does nit capture that value either.

Do I have this backwards?

Comment: So the value from SO Line user field should be copied to the ARTran user field, when the invoice is created?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing it into more details, you could override the Prepare Invoice method on SOOrderEntry graph (and also anywhere else is needed).

By overriding the PrepareInvoice Method of SOOrderEntry graph you could add  a Handler(RowInserting) to SOInvoiceEntry graph to populate your new Custom field with the value on SOOrder.

See sample below where I'm doing similar action copying value from SOOrder(Header) to ARTran(details).

You can use this sample  to achieve your goal: (In your case you could use ARInvoice instead of ARTran)

SOOrderEntry:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public PXAction<SOOrder> prepareInvoice;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Prepare Invoice", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]

    [PXButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable PrepareInvoice(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOInvoiceEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<ARTran>((sender, e) =>
            {
                //Custom logic goes here
                var row = (ARTran)e.Row;

                if (row == null)
                    return;

                SOOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
                if (order != null)
                {
                    var tranExt = PXCache<ARTran>.GetExtension<ARTranExt>(row);

                    //Below to be change to your needs
                    //Here you can look for the SOLine of the SOOrder instead

                    var orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(order);

                    if (orderExt != null && tranExt != null)
                    {
                        tranExt.UsrContactID = orderExt.UsrContactID;
                    }
                    //END
                }                 
            });
        });

        return Base.prepareInvoice.Press(adapter);
    }
}
```

You could also find more information and instructions provided by my colleague on the stackoverflow link below:

[Acumatica custom field SOLine transferred to ARTran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167541/acumatica-custom-field-soline-transferred-to-artran?rq=1)